# Apply multiple criteria to select current and prior row - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
person_id  source_system   r_diff
  1              O          NULL
  1              O           0
  1              O           9
  1              O           NULL
  2              O           574
  2              I           20
  2              O           135
  2              O           0
  2              I           21
  2              O           2
  2              O           0
  2              O           0
  2              I           12
```

I would like to select rows based on the criteria below

criteria 1 - pick all rows where source-system = `I`

criteria 2 - pick prior row (n-1) only when source-system of (n-1)th is `O` and diff is zero.

This criteria 2 should be applied only when nth row has source-system = `I`. If source-system of (n-1)th is `I`, we don't have to do anything because criteria 1 will handle that.

We have to apply both the criteria each person

I tried the below based on SO suggestion but not sure how to make it work

```
m1 = df['visit_source_value'] == 'I'
m2 = df['diff'] <= 0
m3 = df.groupby('person_id')['diff'].shift(-1) <= 0 

df = df1[m1 | m2 | m3]
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
  2              I           20
  2              O           0
  2              I           21
  2              O           0
  2              I           12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer not one line solution, because hard readable if more complicated code, so better is use:

```
m1 = df['visit_source_value'] == 'I'
m2 = df['r_diff'] <= 0
m3 = df.groupby('person_id')['visit_source_value'].shift(-1) == 'I'

df = df[m1 | (m2 & m3)]

print (df)
    person_id visit_source_value  r_diff
5           2                  I    20.0
7           2                  O     0.0
8           2                  I    21.0
11          2                  O     0.0
12          2                  I    12.0
```

Comment: would have done more or less the same, I agree on the idea of splitting the masks

Comment: Well... Is this different from mine?

Comment: yes, it's splitting the condition in masks, much more readable

Comment: well, this happens all the time, don't get frustrated, this was simple question & simple answer, not really worth being mad about anything no? there are many time where I simply don't post when there is something similar to what I've done (like here)

Comment: @U12-Forward - 
Just tested and difference is your solution not tested per groups for `I`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in one-line:

```
>>> df[df['source_system'].eq('I') | (df['source_system'].shift(-1).eq('I') & df['r_diff'].le(0))]
    person_id source_system  r_diff
5           2             I    20.0
7           2             O     0.0
8           2             I    21.0
11          2             O     0.0
12          2             I    12.0
>>>
```

Comment: you shouldn't need to test `df['source_system'].eq('O')` (unless OP failed to mention that other values are possible)

Comment: @mozway Ah yes! Edited my answer